# Online travel agent leaving and returning with different airlines

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, tips-and-tricks

I have noticed that with all online travel sites, you have to leave and return on the same airline (or partner) for international trips.  Is there a way around this?  It seems as though when you try to book a one-way flight it always ends up the same price as a return.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Give some steps to reproduce? What travel site do you using?

Comment: Search for one-way tickets and see if each leg on a separate booking is cheaper?

Answer (score 4):

It depends - for example, in South America - a return flight is almost always cheaper than a oneway flight.  I have no idea why, but seriously, this often works out.

What I do is load up kayak.co.uk or similar flight search engine.  I do 3 searches:

1. A return flight search
2. A one way search to destination
3. A one way search back from destination

This way, if  two individual airlines are cheaper than sticking with one, then you'll find it.  Ie if 2+3 < 1, you win! And if not, then you rest easy that you've gotten a great rate.

If you're really fussy, as I was a few years ago, you can search intermediate locations.  I found four separate airlines that got me to Cairo and back on 4 flights, which worked out cheaper than a direct :)

(London to Brussels to Cairo, to Cologne to London)

Answer (score 3):

This depends on airline policy - because they don't want to send airplane from A to B full of people and return it empty - this causes that two one way tickets are more expensive than one two way ticket with one company ( they have insurance that you will fly both ways )

Comment: Not always (see my South American comment) - it's weird, but seriously a return flight from La Paz to Santiago was cheaper than a one way with the same airline.

Comment: dind't you mind that return flight from La PAz to Santiago wasn't cheaper than a two one way with the same airline. - then my answer will not always work

Comment: I seem to be confusing.  It was cheaper than two one way flights - because it was cheaper than ONE one way flight.  It really was that cheap.  Just checked two arbitrary dates in August with LAN - ONE one way flight to Santiago: 617 pounds.  A return flight - 354 pounds.  Go figure.

Comment: it is exactly what i said , that one two way is cheaper than two one way :-) so now to figure out who is more confused

Comment: How much wood could a wood chuck chuck? ;)  Yeah,  I think we're botn on the same line now, I read 'two one way' as 'one two way' somewhere and it went off on a tangent, haha - both saying the same thing in the end :)  Although your statement 'return flight from LaPaz to Santiago wasn't cheaper than two one way' - not true, it WAS cheaper than two one ways - in fact, it's cheaper than even ONE one way :)  But yeah, I guess the overall point is - it's always worth pricing one way, return, and two one-ways with different airlines, as as you put it - airlines have different policies :)